# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_active'

Tags: javascript, django, django-authentication, parsley.js, nonetype

I'm trying to set up a front-end user authentication check with Parsley.js and Django.
This is my view

```
@requires_csrf_token
def password_check(request):
    email = request.POST.get('email')
    password = request.POST.get('password1')
    user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

    if request.is_ajax():
        if user.is_active:
            res = "These password and e-mail are ok."
            ajax_vars_login = {'response': res, 'email': email, 'password': password}
            json_data_login = json.dumps(ajax_vars_login)
        else:
            res = "The e-mail or the password field aren't correct."
            ajax_vars_login = {'response': res, 'email': email, 'password': password}
            json_data_login = json.dumps(ajax_vars_login)

        return HttpResponse(json_data_login, content_type='application/json')
```

The validator

```
Parsley.addAsyncValidator(
  'emailPwCombination', function (xhr) {
       var password = $('#password').parsley();
       var email = $('#email').parsley();
       var response = xhr.responseText;
       var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(response);
       var jsonResponseText = jsonResponse["response"];

       if(jsonResponseText == 'The password and e-mail are ok.')
           return true;
       if(jsonResponseText == '404')
           return false;
  }, '/password_check/'
);
```

But when the "password_check" function is called I get this error:
**AttributeError at /password_check/

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_active'**

I've tried to put a *print* after "request.is_ajax()" to test the values, and it sometimes catches the e-mail and sometimes the password, but never the two together.

How could I fix that?

Comment: It's telling you that nothing is being returned from `authenticate`, presumably because the email and password do not match. You should be checking for that.

Answer (score 2):

When using `authenticate` function of django, user object is only returned when authentication is successful.

When incorrect credentials are supplied, `authenticate` returns `None`. This is why you are getting `AttributeError`.

To solve this, add an additional check for user, like this:

```
if user and user.is_active:
```

This way, user's `is_active` attribute will only be checked if user exists.

Comment: I don't get the AttributeError anymore - and the function is correctly called -, but still I can't get the two values at the same time: always one or the other.

Comment: Which values are you talking about?

Comment: "email" and "password"

Comment: It's like this: 
{password: "password", response: "The e-mail or the password field aren't correct.", email: null}

Comment: The email value appears to be `null`. Are you sure that the email is being sent properly to django server? have you checked the headers in your browser's network tab?

Comment: Whenever I press the submit button I get two responses: one is the above-quoted, the other is this: {password: null, response: "The e-mail or the password field aren't correct.",…}, so yeah, it's like if the email isn't sent to the server. Thanks, anyway, I'll open a new question.